# Remove extra height space after each container

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple responsive grid layout with image and text below, so I do

```css
.programs_content {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding-top: 4em;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

.rect-img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.rect-img-container::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.rect-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="programs_content">
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text1</span>
  </div>
  

  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="2.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text2</span>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="3.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text3</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="4.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text4</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

But for some reason the height of each square is too much, I want to limit it just before each text. I try to add `position: absolute` to `rect-img` class and it remove some space but the text under the image disappear. How can I solve this? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're aiming for responsive, use flexbox on .rect-img-container

```
  .programs_content {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding-top: 4em;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, 1fr);
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 10px;
  }

  .rect-img-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; /* or space-around || space-evenly */
  }

  .rect-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try with this. I believe this will solve your problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="programs_content">
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text1</span>
  </div>
  

  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text2</span>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text3</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rect-img-container">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="rect-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="" />
    </a>
    <span class="caption">text4</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.programs_content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.rect-img-container {
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
}

.caption {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

I kept it minimalist so that it's easy to understand. The main concept is finalising our grid's element and deciding how one element will looks like.